# Is there a way to handle gesture end (touch up) in iOS version of MPAndroidChart framework?

Tags: android, ios, charts, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

In Android version of **MPAndroidChart** framework there's a method called `onChartGestureEnd` which triggers on touch up (e.g. when you finished dragging your line chart).

Is there an analogue of this method in iOS version of this framework (**Charts**). If no then how can I handle end of dragging (maybe with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`) without damaging the current dragging behaviour of my chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions was to add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the chart and add whatever behaviour you need if the gesture is finished:

```
@IBAction func didDragChart(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        // Whatever you want to do when finished dragging.
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

However it's not enough since charts in this framework already have a default behaviour for dragging. To allow more than one gesture of the same kind (in our case it's dragging) you can create a new subclass of your chart and override this method:

```
 override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: NSUIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: NSUIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Now the both scrolling the chart with dragging (the default behaviour) and your gesture recognizer will work together.